# Bad rendering on iPad mini

Tags: bug, design

[image]

See on the right hand side a bug in rendering on the iPad mini's browser...

Comment: Same problem on other stack exchange websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This and other variations have been posted on Meta.SO several times.

One example: [All Stack Exchange sites in a small window causing display problems?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114636/169404)

I also posted the same thing you are reported and was told by a diamond that it is a known issue (I deleted the question).